# how to upload image in flutter using dio

Tags: flutter, dio

Good day I know that this has been answered, but I'm still unable to figure out what's wrong with my code. I would like some help on how to upload a single image file using dio. I'm able to send the request successfully but the response does not contain the image.

but when I send using postman all works just fine.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

class Upload{

  static Future<bool> wall_add(owner_guid, poster_guid, post, tags, privacy, type, photo) async {
    var fileName = photo.path.split('/').last;
    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "ossn_photo": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        photo.path,
        filename: fileName,
      ),
      "api_key_token" : env['API_KEY'],
      "owner_guid" : owner_guid,
      "poster_guid" : poster_guid,
      "type" : type,
    });

    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.post("${env['URL']}/wall_add", data: data)
        .then((response) {
          print(response);
          return (true);
        })
        .catchError((error) => print(error));
    return (false);
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe this will help you pass the content type in headers `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', `

Comment: thanks it worked after adding the ``` contentType: MediaType("image", "jpeg"), ```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload image as multimedia but you can also convert it into `Base64` format and then send.